# getting this error while reading the list box via selenium webdriver:

Tags: selenium-webdriver, listbox

The error I am getting: Element should have been "select" but was "input"

Now Code I am using is as below :-

```
     List <WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[4]/div/section[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[9]/div[1]/span/span[1]/span/ul/li/input"));

     for (WebElement e : myElements)
     {
        System.out.println(e.getText());

        }  

     for(WebElement e : myElements) {
         if(e.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("islamabad")) {
             e.click();
         }
       }
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group input_border_bottom" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : agentForm.district.$invalid && !agentForm.district.$pristine }">
<div class="left">
<select id="district" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" ng-model="agent.district" name="district" multiple="" ui-select2="select2Options" data-placeholder="Select Districts" ng-required="true" required="required" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;">
<span class="selection">
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="combobox" tabindex="-1">
<ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
<li class="select2-search select2-search--inline">
<input class="select2-search__field" type="search" aria-autocomplete="list" role="textbox" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" placeholder="Select Districts" style="width: 742px;">
</li>
</ul>
</span>
</span>
<span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: `selectByVisibleText` operates on `<select>`s and selects an `<option>` in it

Comment: it is not throwing any error now, but also the value is not selected. when i get size of WebElement it returns me 1. it means all values are not getting stored in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because your dropdown is not created by `select` tag but form `input` tag and you are trying to execute select code for same. See the HTML you have shared is having `input` not `select`

You haven't post necessary HTML code still I have created a XPath for you

```
//input[@class='select2-search__field' and @role='role' and @placeholder='Select Districts']
```

Click it like you do for normal click operation

OR

First find a xpath which will return you all values of dropdown. Then using List you can select any value.

```
   List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='select2-search__field' and @role='role' and @placeholder='Select Districts']"));
   for(WebElement e : myElements) {
     if(e.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Your_Desire_Value")) {
         e.click();
     }
```

Note :- click on the dropdown first using simple click operation and then use above code. may you also need to apply focus if value is present in deep below in list

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: It worked i was giving wrong xpath before. But when i gave the xpath of whole block it selected the value. Thanks you